# Use CSV to populate Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am very new for Neo4j. I am a learner of this graph database. I need to load a csv file into Neo4j database. I am trying from 2 days,I couldn't able to find good information of reading the csv file in to Neo4j. Please suggest me wil sample code or blogs of reading csv file into Neo4j.

Example:
Suppose if i have a csv file in This way how can we read it into Neo4j

```
id  name    language
1   Victor Richards West Frisian
2   Virginia Shaw   Korean
3   Lois Simpson    Belarusian
4   Randy Bishop    Hiri Motu
5   Lori Mendoza    Tok Pisin
```

Answer (score 4):

You may want to try https://github.com/sroycode/neo4j-import

This populates data directly from a pair of CSV files ( entries must be COMMA separated )

To build: (you need maven)

```
sh build.sh
```

The nodes file has a mandatory field id and any other fields you like

```
NODES.txt
id,name,language
1,Victor Richards,West Frisian
2,Virginia Shaw,Korean
3,Lois Simpson,Belarusian
```

The relationships file has 3 mandatory fields from,to,type. Assuming you have a field age ( long integer), and info, the relations file will look like

```
RELNS.txt
from,to,type,age@long,info
1,2,KNOWS,10,known each other from school
1,3,CLUBMATES,5,member of country club
```

Running:

```
sh run.sh graph.db NODES.txt RELNS.txt
```

will create graph.db in the current folder which you can copy to the neo4j data folder.

Note:
If you are using neo4j later than 1.6.* , please add this line in conf/neo4j.properties

```
allow_store_upgrade = true
```

Have fun.

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at https://github.com/jexp/batch-import

Can be used as starting point

Comment: look even at Michaels recent experiment, http://jexp.de/blog/2012/10/parallel-batch-inserter-with-neo4j/

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing available to generically load CSV data into Neo4j because the source and destination data structures are different: CSV data is tabular whereas Neo4j holds graph data.

In order to achieve such an import, you will need to add a separate step to translate your tabular data into some form of graph (e.g. a tree) before it can be loaded into Neo4j. Taking the tree structure further as an example, the page below shows how XML data can be converted into Cypher which may then be directly executed against a Neo4j instance.

http://geoff.nigelsmall.net/xml2graph/

Please feel free to use this tool if it helps (bear in mind it can only deal with small files) but this will of course require you to convert your CSV to XML first.

Cheers

Nigel

Comment: pretty nifty tool.  Would love to see that work on large data sets ;)

Comment: I recently added options to py2neo to load XML (http://book.py2neo.org/en/latest/geoff.html#module-functions). This is essentially a python rewrite of the xml2graph page above.

Comment: very cook.  I will check that out

Comment: So basically Neo4j is so new that you have to code your own CSV importer?

Answer (score 1):

there is probably no known CSV importer for neo4j, you must import it yourself:

i usually do it myself via gremlin's g.loadGraphML(); function.
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/gremlin-plugin.html#rest-api-load-a-sample-graph

i parse my data with some external script into the xml syntax and load the particular xml file. you can view the syntax here:
https://raw.github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/master/data/graph-example-1.xml
parsing an 100mb file takes few minutes.

in your case what you need to do is a simple bipartite graph with vertices consisting of users and languages, and edges of "speaks". if you know some programming, then create **user nodes** with parameters **id**, **name** | unique **language nodes** with parameters **name** | **relationships** where you need to connect each user with the particular language. note that users can be duplicite whereas languages can't.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question is too generic. What does your csv file contain? Logical meaning of the contents of a csv file can vary very much. An example of two columns with IDs, which would represent entities connected to each other.

```
3921  584
831   9891
3841  92
...
```

In this case you could either write a BatchInserter code snippet which would import it faster, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/batchinsert.html.

Or you could import using regular GraphDatabaseService with transaction sizes of a couple of thousands inserts for performance. See how to setup and use the graph db at http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/tutorials-java-embedded.html.

Comment: Hi,please check the above file. I have update sample csv file. I already gone through the above links which u have referred. but i am not able to understand how it reads csv file